# How delete files with special characters using fs.unlink

Tags: node.js

I have a function that loops through a folder(`fs.readdir`) and delete all files in there using `fs.unlink` for each file.

The problem is that some files has specials characters and can't be deleted because I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './temp_files/Some�s in File�dio.txt'
```

Clearly, the problem is because of the ???. But I haven't found a way to fix it.

How can I do it?

Comment: What operating system is this? I just tried doing this and it went through without issues - used special character and spaces. I am using Linux

Comment: Are you running your code from the same directory in which the program is? Or are you running it from a different directory? Since you are using relative paths, the path will not be the same if you are running it from a different directory.

Comment: Its one up folder. The problem is not the path because all the other files get removed. Just when is like the file above that is not.

Answer (score 0):

I could not fin an answer for this... what I did was to change the name of the file when uploading it. In my case I use MULTER with NODE.JS on the backend so, this does the trick:

```
storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: ....,
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        let newName = file.originalname
            .normalize('NFD')
            .replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
        newName = newName
            .split(' ')
            .join('_')
            .toLowerCase();
        cb(null, newName);
    }
});
```

What it does is removes every special character, removes every space cause that will also give you trouble and replace those with an underscore. Hope it works for you